# Review or Simulation to make user to have right access

Tags: user, sql-analysis-services

When you work for a organization that has about 300 users in a SharePoint solution and I need to review if right user has access to right page to right information. Is there a simulation approach to review it? It's possible to do it in SSAS.

Answer (score 0):

Under permissions for the element you want to test. Fx a page you can control permissions. If the permissions is in another scope this approach will not work, as it's only for SharePoint users.

The following example is in danish but the icons are the same. 
[image: Test permissions]

Test the permissions on the element by entering the user or group. 
[image: Enter the user or group to test]